# Presenting view controller response touch events when modal view controller is presented

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, touch-event

Here is the code:

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *presentedViewController = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdentifierName"];
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

presentingViewController presentViewController:presentedViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

the view of presentingViewController would not response any touch event, but I want it to take touch events,what should I do? Appreciate for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior and should be what you see in most apps. Apple's App Store app does allow you to tap outside the modal form sheet to dismiss it, however, so there's some precedent for it being acceptable, in a limited way. If your design absolutely requires it, consider setting up and tearing down a window-based gesture recognizer in the presented view controller.

For example, to implement the tap-outside-to-dismiss behavior, configure a tap gesture recognizer in `viewDidAppear:`. You can remove it on `viewWillDisappear:` if it still exists at the time that is called.

In the tap handler, you'd want to get the location of the tap in window coordinates, ie:

```
CGPoint tapPoint = [recognizer locationInView:nil];
```

You could then do some work with geometry to check and see if the tap occurred on the modally-presented view or outside (over the dimmed region that corresponds to your presenting view controller). UIView has a `pointInside:withEvent:` method that might help with that.

Comment: I appreciate your response,but I'm confused in which view I should override pointInside:withEvent:  method,and what should I do in this method

Comment: In the tap recognizer, once you have the tap location, you can call [self.view pointInside:tapPoint withEvent:nil] to see if the tap occurred on the modal view or outside it. You may need to convert the tapPoint from window coordinates to the coordinates of the modal view using convertPoint:fromView before testing it with pointInside:withEvent.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand what you mean, the tap recognizer is added by the modal view, so only in the modal view the tap recognizer can be recognized, which means it makes no sense to call [self.view pointInside:tapPoint withEvent:nil]

Comment: Of course, the tap recognizer is added in self.view.window, I got it wrong before. Then judge if the tap is on the modal view or outside, you are right, and problem solved.Thanks a lot,you are a life saver.

Answer (score -5):

Here is the simple way to present viewcontroller...

```
  ViewController *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
  [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Enjoy code

Comment: I don't think you understand exactly what I mean

Comment: This just launches the modal view.  These two lines will not allow touch response on the presentation view controller.  Just show the overlaying modal view.  bhoomi-thummar you should self remove this solution.